# Неправильно сериализует имя input поля

Tags: jquery, serialize, javascript

Есть такой Html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="100">
```

При сериализации формы, имя **type[]** инпут поля, кодируется спецсимволами и возникает два **type** :

```
type%5B%5D=19&type%5B%5D=2
```

Сама сериализация:

```
var formData = $(element).closest('form').serialize();
    console.log(formData);
```

Comment: Всё правильно. На сервере получите массив в $_POST['type']

Comment: На сервер приходит ерунда вот такая:
    string(236) "type[]=19&type;[]=2&type;[]=3&subject=s1&message=s2

Comment: Я бы удивился, если бы было что-то другое.

    parse_str($_POST['formData'], $arrData);
    var_dump($arrData);

Comment: Сейчас проверим...с parse_str тоже был подобный трабл

Comment: Да, пожалуйста все тоже с parse_str:

array(5) {
  ["type"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "19"
  }
  ["type;"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  ["subject;"]=>
  string(8) "Тема"
  ["message;"]=>

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, и что же вам не нравится в последнем варианте?

> Обратите внимание на: ["type;"] и
> ["message;"

Вы уверены, что в атрибутах name, у элементов формы, точки с запятой нет?

Comment: Уверен полностью:

<input type="checkbox" value="19" name="type[]"><label for="164932274476.1485">Aliev</label></div></li><li>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="type[]">

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, в мистику, а особенно в отношении программирования, я не верю. Если отметить эти два checkbox-а, и передать ajax-запросом, то получим такой массив:

    array(1) {
      ["type"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(2) "19"
        [1]=>
        string(1) "2"
      }
    }

Comment: Какая версия jquery? Есть ли религия, которая не позволяет сделать

    var data = {};
    $('form.superform').find('input, button, textarea').each(function(){
        data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    });

?